# How to translate this cURL command to a VB?

Tags: vb.net, curl, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to translate the following cURL command that extrats a .diff content in GitHub to VB:

```
    curl -H 'Authorization: token myGitHubToken' -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.diff" https://api.github.com/repos/[USR]/[REPO]/commits/[COMMITID]
```

The cURL works fine. And my code in VB with `HttpWebRequest` is

```
    Dim url As New Uri("https://api.github.com/repos/[USR]/[REPO]/commits/[COMMITID]")
    Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
    SetAllowUnsafeHeaderParsing20()
    myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization: token myGitHubToken")
    myReq.Accept("application/vnd.github.v3.diff")
    myReq.KeepAlive = False
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(myReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

But in `GetResponse`, throws me a `WebException` :

> "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden"

Is ok my traslation? There is something wrong?

Comment: I take it `[USR]`, `[REPO]` and `[COMMITID]` along with `myGitHubToken` are just placeholders so you can post the code here and are actual values when you attempt to `GetResponse`? (I'm not familiar with the API but just want to clarify)

Comment: Yes, are just placeholders

Comment: OK, thanks. First thing to note `myReq.Accept("application/vnd.github.v3.diff")` should be `myReq.Accept = "application/vnd.github.v3.diff"`. Also `myReq.Headers.Add()` can accept a header and a value for example `myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "myGitHubToken")` whether this would make a difference?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First `myReq.Accept("application/vnd.github.v3.diff")` was a mistake. In my code appears  `myReq.Accept = "application/vnd.github.v3.diff`.
Second, i've tried with `myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "token myGitHubToken")`, and still throws the same exception

Comment: Might be worth looking at an alternative way if using .NET. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net)